# MSBuild.exe not creating folders inside "bin"

Tags: xml, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a few files which i want to be copied inside a folder inside bin.

For example, abc.xslt is a file in "Tom" folder.

abc.xslt's properties

- Build Action :  Content
- Copy to output directory : Copy always

When I build my project from Visual studio I get following folder structure which is correct

bin -> Tom -> abc.xslt

But when i build using command prompt with MSBuild, I dont get the folder "Tom"

bin -> abc.xslt.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" "project.sln" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true /p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=none /m /p:OutDir="D:\bin" /p:Configuration="Staging" /p:Platform="Any Cpu"
```

Guide me.

Comment: I create a simple console App with folder named Tom and xslt file named abc, i remove the property named Staging, it works. Please share a simple demo which can reproduce the issue via OneDrive.

Comment: what kind of template you are using(c#, c++, or other), please try to build the solution via visual studio and check if it works, you can change output path via right click project -> properties -> build -> output Path -> change the path as you want. Here is a demo, which work well with msbuild command. if the demo works, please compare the xx.csproj file with yours. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDfRdSmTF9SszGxTw

Answer (score 0):

Param OutputPath has priority over OutDir, you may try using /p:OutputPath="pathtobin"

Check which of these properties is being used within your csproj